# redirect port 80 to 443, or ssl redirection

Tags: codeigniter

I am using Cloudways server in order to redirect my http site to https i have install the certificaiton and now its working but if i am using 
myhost.com in url baar the sites open and the site not redirect into https://www.myhost.com
in order to do force ssl i am using this code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myhost\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.myhost.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /index\.php(/[^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^index\.php(/(.*))?$ myhost.com/$2 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

However it is also not working and give me the error of too many redirects i am also using hooks ssl code

```
<?php
function redirect_ssl() {
$CI =& get_instance();
$class = $CI->router->fetch_class();
$exclude =  array('client');  // add more controller name to exclude ssl.
if(!in_array($class,$exclude)) {
    // redirecting to ssl.
    $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('http://', 'https://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
    if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] != 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
} else {
    // redirecting with no ssl.
    $CI->config->config['base_url'] = str_replace('https://', 'http://', $CI->config->config['base_url']);
    if ($_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'] == 443) redirect($CI->uri->uri_string());
}
```

}

it is also not working somebody please suggest me what can i do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this much less complex solution that works for most CI installations.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

With the above in place, there is no need for the hook routine. Just set `config['base_url'] =  "https://myhost.com/";` and be done with it.

Comment: Hi i have done the same but still the error message showing as too many redirects. And now i have removed the hooks also.

Comment: Is it possible that some other piece of code is calling `redirect()`?